# lein ring uberwar NullPointerException

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Working backwards from [example ch17-webapp-lein](https://github.com/clojurebook/ClojureProgramming/tree/master/ch17-webapp-lein) in ["Clojure Programming"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449394701) by Emerick, Carper, and Grand, I've boiled my web service down to the bare minimum, hoping to deploy it to Elastic Beanstalk. I now have a repeatable `NullPointerException` in `lein ring uberwar.`  I'd appreciate any help diagnosing or debugging this, or relaying it to the right people.

Here is my `project.clj`

```
(defproject com.clojurebook/sample-lein-web-project "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]
                 [compojure/compojure "1.0.0"]
                 [ring "1.1.8"]]
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.6.2"]
            [lein-beanstalk "0.2.7"]]
  :ring {:handler com.clojurebook.hello-world/routes})
```

and here is the one and only `src` file in the project

```
(ns com.clojurebook.hello-world
  (:use
    [compojure.core :only (GET HEAD defroutes)]))

(defroutes routes
  (HEAD "/" [] "")
  (GET "*" request "hello"))
```

When I do

```
lein ring uberwar
```

in the project directory, I get

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at clojure.lang.Numbers.ops(Numbers.java:942)
    at clojure.lang.Numbers.isZero(Numbers.java:90)
    at leiningen.ring.uberwar$uberwar.invoke(uberwar.clj:45)
    at leiningen.ring.uberwar$uberwar.invoke(uberwar.clj:43)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
    at leiningen.ring$ring.doInvoke(ring.clj:19)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:419)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
    at leiningen.core.main$resolve_task$fn__1836.doInvoke(main.clj:149)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:139)
    at clojure.lang.AFunction$1.doInvoke(AFunction.java:29)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
    at leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invoke(main.clj:189)
    at leiningen.core.main$resolve_and_apply.invoke(main.clj:193)
    at leiningen.core.main$_main$fn__1899.invoke(main.clj:257)
    at leiningen.core.main$_main.doInvoke(main.clj:247)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:419)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:617)
    at clojure.main$main_opt.invoke(main.clj:335)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:440)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:457)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:427)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:172)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to [lein-ring 0.8.5](https://github.com/weavejester/lein-ring) fixed this.